# List_view getting items back 

Tags: android

I have 3 different function in an activity namely , main category,sub_category and list of items. By clicking main category it displays sub_category and same like list of item.I want to give back option, in order to view back functions. for example at the time of viewing list_of item by clicking back option, i want to show sub_category and by clicking back button from sub_category i want to display main category. I dont know how to do this.  All the above function are reside in one class. can anyone give solution for this..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override onKeyDown function to handle back key event.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
        // invoke your navigation function
        // return true; - to prevent this event from being propagated further
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for comments.. hey can you explain me more. i dont know what is keycode and keyevent. pls help me

Comment: Simply keyCode is code of key, and KeyEvent is event like ACTION_UP, ACTION_DOWN etc. Was it helpfull?